# Python's setup.py installed CLI script doesn't allow importing same module

Tags: python, module, setuptools

I want to create a python app named knife that can be executed from CLI, the problem is that it can't import the modules. I followed the same folder structure as the Django project for reference.

My directory structure is like this:

```
knife/
    knife/
        bin/
            knife-cli.py
        core/
            main/
                __init__.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

exclude = ['knife.bin']

setup(name='Knife',
      version='0.3',
      description='Very cool project',
      author='John Doe',
      author_email='author@email.com',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=exclude),
      include_package_data=True,
      scripts=['knife/bin/knife-cli.py'],
      entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'knife-cli = knife.core.main:main'
        ]
      },
      zip_safe=False,
     )
```

My `knife/core/main/__init__.py` contains a `main()` function and my `knife/bin/knife-cli.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from knife.core import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main.main()
```

So after installing the module with setup.py install, I try to run knife-cli but keeps on throwing this error:

```
$ knife-cli 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/knife-cli", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Knife==0.3', 'console_scripts', 'knife-cli')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 468, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2563, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/bin/knife.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 646, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1559, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'knife.py'
```

What is really happening? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some more `__init__`'s. The `__init__.py` file tells python that the folder is a python module. You are refrencing these as modules in your setup script, so you need to tell python that they are modules.

```
knife/
    knife/
        bin/
            knife-cli.py
        core/
            main/
                __init__.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

That should fix the main problem. However, you are also declaring two scripts, one using the `scripts` section and another using the `console_scripts`. Console scripts will actually create the script for you, so you dont need to include your own in "bin".

Here is a better setup.py for you: (note I just removed the scripts section)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

exclude = ['knife.bin']

setup(name='Knife',
      version='0.3',
      description='Very cool project',
      author='John Doe',
      author_email='author@email.com',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=exclude),
      include_package_data=True,
      entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'knife-cli = knife.core.main:main'
        ]
      },
      zip_safe=False,
     )
```

Comment: I'm having 2 scripts one is knife-cli and the other is knife-cli.py, it shouldn't be an issue, I've just copied the logic in django's setup.py. I also have my `__init__.py` in core, just forgot to include it.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in the child knife directory as well?

Comment: Yes, I also forgot that.

Comment: Do you think it can be my setuptools version? I'm using 15.2

Comment: @gbriones.gdl 15.2 is the latest, so it should be fine. This is what is telling me that your "scripts" isn't doing what you think: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/knife-cli", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Knife==0.3', 'console_scripts', 'knife-cli')()` 
Just try it without scripts and see what happens.
Youll probably need to do a pip uninstall . first.

Comment: Still the same error. I've also deleted the files tracked with `setup.py install --record files.txt` and the build and dist folders. Have you tried this in your own environment?

Comment: I can also run `$ ./knife/bin/knife-cli.py` without a problem. It prints `Execute main function`

Answer (score 5):

Got it, The script was executing the old `/usr/bin/knife.pyc` file, I just deleted it and now works well.

Comment: FML. I spent way too long (like 4 hours) working on this. It would be swell if Python would consistently recognize outdated artifacts.